# Access Key Vault on Azure Service Fabric app using Azure Active Directory on different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault, azure-security

I have Azure service fabric cluster in **tenantA** which needs to connect to Azure key vault in ***tenantB*** to load up some of the connection strings required for its applications hosted on it

Thought of trying out the below set-up:

1. to establish the handshake between the service fabric cluster in **tenantA** and Azure key vault in ***tenantB*** is by using Azure AD Application belongs to ***tenantB***.
2. configure Azure AD Application ID which belongs to ***tenantB*** to Azure service fabric application config in **tenantA**
3. add Azure AD Application ID to the access policy of Azure key vault in ***tenantB***

With this setup, will handshake between Azure service fabric cluster and Azure key vault happen?

(or)

Azure service fabric cluster, Azure key vault & Azure AD application have to be in same tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Application Id used to access the Key Vault is in the same tenant as the Key Vault, the application can run from anywhere.  The application (with application id) will acquire an access token from its own tenant and then use that to access the Key Vault.  The environment executing the code can have identities from multiple tenants when using an application id and secret.

Comment: @ Matt Small, now we are right to the point. thanks. can you explain how my application running on tenantA will have visibility/identify some azure AD app belongs to tenantB?

Comment: Your code that creates the client requires a service principal in the same tenant as the key vault.  The code can execute from anywhere.  When the code creates the client, it acquires an auth token from the Key Vault's tenant and uses that to get the secret.  Once that secret is obtained, it can be used by the application anywhere.


If this was not true, then on-prem applications would not be able to call Key Vault.

Comment: @ Matt Small, so to obtain auth token, client makes call to AAD OAuth endpoint & supply application id & respective secret/certificate. Then it is responsibility of  AAD OAuth endpoint to 1) verify existence of application id across ANY tenant on the Azure, 2) do validation with secret/certificate then issue access token to the calling App regardless of to which tenant the calling App belongs. Is this flow correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The AAD OAuth endpoint can validate a service principal (registered app) across any tenant.  However, when it issues the token, the token must match up to an identity in an access policy in Key Vault.  That means that the identity is in the same tenant as the Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

> With this setup, will handshake between Azure service fabric cluster and Azure key vault happen?

It will not work, when you add the tenantB AD App Application ID to the access policy of Azure key vault in tenantB, essentially you add the service principal corresponded to the AD App to the keyvault. A service principal is a specific instance for an AD App in one tenant, it just works for the tenant which it located.

Even you consent the tenantB AD App to tenantA via the [admin consent URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent), it just generates a new service principal(enterprise application) in tenantA, which is not the same object as that you added in keyvault, an AD App has a 1:many relationship with its corresponding service principal.

> Azure service fabric cluster, Azure key vault & Azure AD application have to be in same tenant?

Not exactly, but at least the service fabric cluster and key vault need to be in the same tenant, the AD App can be in another tenant, but it should be a [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant), then you need to consent it to the tenant of keyvault and service fabric cluster as mentioned above, then add the new generated service principal to the access policy before using it in service fabric cluster. If you not very familiar with Azure AD, it will be a little complex, so I recommend you to use them in the same tenant.

For more details about the relationship between AD Application and service principal, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

Comment: Any way I can have Azure AD app & KeyVault in same tenant but Azure SF cluster on another tenant and still connect Azure SF cluster & KeyVault for app secret?

Comment: @ Joy Wang, this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#example) says service principal created on other tenant can be configured against home tenant keyvault, am I right on this?

Comment: @ZackieKhan Maybe I misunderstood your meaning. 1.If you are connecting azure keyvault in SF cluster with the tenant id, client id and secret, I think it can be in another tenant. 2.No, a service principal just works for the tenant it located, if it locates in a consumer tenant, it will not work in the home tenant.

Comment: @ZackieKhan Could you share the doc you referred to about connecting keyvault in SF cluster?

Comment: I'm referring "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#example" As mentioned in the flow diagra, could you explain how HR App's service principal of contoso/fabrikam connecting to HR APP keys of Adatum tenant?